# Encrypt Excel file on Windows for use on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-excel, encryption

I have an Excel file open using Excel 2007 on a Vista PC.

I wish to encrypt this file, and send it to someone to open on a Mac running Excel 11.6.6 (Office 2004). Is this easily achievable?

I understand the Mac won't open Excel 2007 .xlsx documents. I thought that it may open files saved in the format for 97-2003, however I'm not confident in using its default encryption method in the older format. I saw something about selecting an encryption type but couldn't find that option on my version of Excel.

I'd rather not have the Mac user jump through any hoops or install software. But maybe that's the only option? I understand he won't even be able to open a passworded zip file without extra software?

Thanks :D

Comment: In the end I uploaded a compatible file onto an encrypted/passworded web server for the mac user to download. It'll do :)